# How divide resource file on several parts in subdirectories

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

As example: file `res/values/strings.xml` is too huge. 
How i can devide it using `<include>` or something like that?
I would like to have
`strings/actions.xml`
`strings/texts.xml`
`strings/font_icons.xml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can easily create others string.xml like constant.xml etc.

values folder ->

1. constant.xml
2. string.xml
3. language.xml

Edit Post :

Add below code in a gradle in android tag:

```
android {
 sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/values/campaign',
                            'src/main/res/values',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create sub folders?

Comment: where is "gradle"?

Comment: i have posted the code of gradle just put the below code in your app build.gradle in android tag
sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/values/campaign',
                            'src/main/res/values',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }

Comment: I can't find it. Maybe it's some specific file for Android Studio? I don't use it

Comment: Yes it is android studio project structure file. Are you using eclipse.?

Comment: No, I use NetBeans, but I understand the idea)